# Определение букв в input()

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

```
a = input("Напишите любое число или цифру")
if int(a)= 
    input(a + '+3=1?') #Ответ всегда "Да"
b = -2
if int(a) > b:
    print('Ложь')
elif int(a) < b:
    print('Ложь')
elif int(a) == b:
    print ('Правда')
```

Как во второй строке сделать определение букв с возвращением в первую строку?
То есть если в input() ввели слово или букву, то возвращается в первую строку и выводит "Напишите любое число или цифру"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверяйте ответ через [str.isdecimal()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isdecimal#str.isdecimal).

Пример использования:

```
while True:
    num_str = input('Input number: ')

    # Если ввели число, выходим из цикла
    if num_str.isdecimal():
        break

print('num_str:', num_str)

num = int(num_str)
print('num:', num)
```

Другой способ через парсинг строки в число и отлов исключения:

```
while True:
    num_str = input('Input number: ')

    
    try:
        num = int(num_str)

        # Если дошли до этого места, исключения не было, а значит строка валидная
        break

    except ValueError:
        pass

print('num:', num)
```

Comment: При вводе -2 он также возвращается в начало

Comment: Попробуйте заменить: `if num_str.isdecimal():` -> `num_str.lstrip('-').isdecimal()`. Но мне кажется вариант с try/except будет проще :)